# Paginate the CSV (Python)

Tags: python

How can I paginate through the CSV version of an API call using Python?

I understand the metadata in the JSON call includes the total number of records, but without similar info in the CSV call I won't know where to stop my loop if I try to increment the page parameter.

Below is my code:

```
url = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.csv'

payload = {
    'api_key': '4KC***UNKk',
    'fields': 'school.name,2012.repayment.2_yr_default_rate',
    '_page' : '0'
}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
df = pd.read_csv(r.url)
```

This loads a dataframe with the first 20 results, but I'd like to load a dataframe with all the results.

Comment: You need to include a count and after that count is full than load into dataframe, dirrect load into dataframe will not work due imitations of the api.

Comment: @sb0709 How do I know when to end my count? If I do an extra loop than it breaks.

Comment: No need for breaks, will read everything at each 20 result and will loop till hits 7000 results. Aswer bellow does explain with the api options but I prefer pythonic way of scrapping more, is just my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the `&_per_page` option parameter to edit the number of choices per call; Setting it to `&_per_page=200` returns a CSV with 100 lines, so lets assume 100 is the maximum.

Now that we know the maximum per call, and we have the total calls, its possible to run a for loop to get what we need, like so:

```
url = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.csv'
apikey = '&api_key=xxx'
fields = '&_fields=school.name,2012.repayment.2_yr_default_rate'
pageA = '&_page='
pageTotal = '&_per_page='
pageNumbersMaximum = 10
rowSum = 200
for page in range(pageNumbersMaximum):
    fullURL = url + pageA + str(page) + pageTotal + str(rowSum) + fields + apikey
    print(fullURL)
    print("Page Number: " + str(page) + ", Total Rows: " + str(rowSum))
    rowSum += 200
```

That will loop through the results until it gets to 7000 total.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The challenge here is where to stop the loop. 7000 was just an example. But the issue is that I don't know how many loops to make and generating an extra loop causes an error.

Comment: ok, then each call should be wrapped in try/except and break the loop upon failing. will edit this when i have free time.

Comment: @TimErnst this is actually much more difficult (@ least for me) than it seems...if you exceed the number of responses, you still get a csv download. its bunk, but you still get one. need at least one more layer of authentication...

Comment: @TimErnst this post has actually been quite helpful to me: https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping-cheat-sheet/#handling-network-errors